# What is the usage of WITH_DEXPREOPT environment variable?

Tags: android-source

I was building Android Source Code after adding my app package in vendor directory. But the make failed saying

```
DWARF ERROR: Invalid pointer.
```

I don't have the exact error with me now, as later after searching for reason I came across a post asking to use

```
export WITH_DEXPREOPT = false
```

before build.So after using this the code built successfully.

Can anyone please explain me the use of the environment variable `WITH_DEXPREOPT`?

(edited)

Small portion of the error logs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO4f1.png)

Answer (score 0):

ART is now the default runtime on Android.

```
WITH_DEXPREOPT := true
```

**This makes an `odexed` build, which seems to significantly improve
boot-time performance after an update.** There's also a major performance improvement when one uses device
encryption. With device encryption, the data partition (containing the
compiled `OAT` files) is not available prior to decryption, yet the system
needs to load most of the frameworks, and a number of packages, simply to
show the decryption prompt and keyboard.

For this reason, devices using encryption take a longtime to boot up to
that prompt. A really long time. If you use WITH_DEXPREOPT, this will
significantly improve boot performance on those devices.

**WITH_DEXPREOPT uses a bit more storage space on
the device.** It's not much for modern high-spec devices, but anything more
legacy may have issues. If you follow the instructions at
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure.html#sample_usage
though, it will guide you through how to progressively reduce what's being
optimised, until you get something that fits on the system, and works.

```
WITH_DEXPREOPT := false
```

**This will create standalone apk without OAT files.**

There's more information available at
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure.html

Comment: So, can it be said that due to optimization of dex file not done properly, the error occurred?

Comment: Above was explanation of the environment variable WITH_DEXPREOPT. If build is failing only with your app then some thing is wrong with your apk. Share the complete error logs.

Comment: I added the small portion of the error logs I got in the above post.